# WPF Application Exit Suspends worker threads

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, deadlock, dispatcher

Consider the following scenario:

I have created a managed wrapper atop of a native API (P/Invoke).
 This API operates a USB device which performs I/O operations on a dedicated thread.
Moreover, this API is single threaded, such that invoking its methods and finalizing it must be done on the same thread which had initialized it.
The gist of it is:

```
//Runs in the context of a new System.Threading.Thread instance
void Loopback()
{
 InitializeAPI();
 try
 {

 while(_work)
 {
  //Poll API
 }
 }
 finally
 {
  FinalizeAPI()
  //Unblock disposing thread
 }
}

void Dispose()
{
  _work=false;
  //Block untill Loopback method returns
}
```

When using the aforementioned wrapper in the context of a WPF application, I call the Dispose method of my wrapper class in the Application.OnExit override. This causes a deadlock.

A single glance at the Thread window in VS clearly shows that the worker thread which was dedicated to the native API is stuck at some wait handle associated with the current WPF Dispatcher. I guess this makes sense since WPF wants everything to suspend when it finalizes.

My Dispose method, on the other hand- must not return until the device's API has finalized, so I wired a TaskCompletionSource to complete its task when the dedicated thread finishes.

What my Dispose method does is to kickoff the thread's end by toggling the loop condition variable and immediately blocking on the TaskCompletionSource's task.

The dedicated thread will never finish since it is blocked by WPF, And the UI thread will never finish since it blocks on a task which will never complete, hence the Deadlock.

Is there a way to overcome this issue while remaining agnostic to client frameworks on the wrapper's side?

Help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: On which thread are you initializing the api? The main thread?

Comment: God forbid, on a dedicated Thread which I explicitly start.

Comment: Then I'm not sure why there would be a deadlock, you dispatch the api finalization on this other thread, join the thread in the main thread, and that should do it?! Does the api have calbacks to the ui logic?

Comment: For the sake of experiment, Start some thread in a WPF app, override the Application.OnExit method and put a breakpoint there.. You will see that your thread's method will await some Dispatcher handle. My guess is that WPF halts all threads when it  performs its exit sequence.

I do not need to dispatch the finalization since I merely flip a boolean field so that the loop which this thread carries out ceases. Problem is that this thread is waiting for some event handle, and will not resume operations until some point in time to which I do not have access. The API has no callbacks.

Comment: Is your dedicated thread a background thread?

Comment: _thread = new Thread(DoWork);

Comment: try adding `_thread.IsBackgroung = true;`

Comment: I will get back to you on that tomorrow. (AFW) Thanks! @PhilippeParé

Comment: It did not help, nor did transitioning the loop into a long running task. @PhilippeParé